# Facebook Graph API - Unpublished posts retrive unordered

Tags: facebook, sorting, facebook-graph-api, timestamp, facebook-fql

I was able to retrieve my page unpublished posts. I'm trying to understand how can i retrieve them sorted by `scheduled_publish_time` (Unix Timestamp) property, **without** having the need to sort them within my app.

As the docs says :

```
Time-based Pagination:
Time pagination is used to navigate through results data using Unix timestamps which point to specific times in a list of data.

When using an endpoint that uses time-based pagination, you will see the following JSON response:

until : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the range of time-based data.
since : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of time-based data.
```

Although, if i set `since` to the current date timestamp, i'm getting empty json(If i'm **not** specifying `since`, i'm getting response with all my unpublished posts).

**Bottom line, How can i  retrieve my unpublished post in `scheduled_publish_time` order?**

Comment: Pagination works on object creation times, I think. If there is no special parameter on that endpoint to have the data sorted the way you want, then it is probably not possible at all.

Comment: @CBroe hmm, so I'll have to fetch all the posts, and order them locally?

Comment: If the docs don’t mention any sorting parameters – then yes.